# node.js execute multiple commands with sudo

Tags: node.js, sudo

In my node.js script, I need to run these two commands with sudo:

```
execSync('sudo rsync -a ' + dir1 + " " + dir2);
execSync('sudo rm -Rf ' + dir1);
```

but this cause that it will ask for sudo password two times;
other than this, if I digit a wrong password, the script goes on without requesting it again;
how can I cache the password to avoid to be prompted for it two times and wait until the correct password is supplied before going on?

Comment: You can login as root and have the permissions (but it's ill-advised).

Comment: Yes this is true but I need to use sudo;

Comment: Well the issue with that is that the whole point of sudo is to give the given user, superuser privileges for one command. Future reference: more background to sudo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960665/whats-the-point-of-permissions-in-linux-if-anyone-can-do-a-sudo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following [this piece of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560442/how-to-run-two-commands-in-sudo), I would also advise to just execute both commands under the same `sudo` command.

```
execSync('sudo -- sh -c \'rsync -a ' + dir1 + ' ' + dir2 + ' && rm -Rf ' + dir1 + '\'');
```

Detecting whether an error occurred can be done from [execSync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-sync) itself. It seems that an exception is thrown when `stderr` is not empty. I would have first suggested to check the command's exit code, but that library does not seem to expose it.

Comment: Too late maybe but replace the ; by && to execute the rm only if the rsync succeed. That could avoid a disaster